# A riddle about one of my favorite things :)

Tags: riddle

```
My source is borne upon the wing of valkyries of gold,

They work their magic summer long then winter through the cold,

Once the black and golds are done I'm plucked with careful hand,

And left to swim among the shrooms until it's time to stand,

And in that time my power grows as was the hand's intent,

Til even mighty fall like fools when my power is spent,

Though fewer know me by the days, some think I'm in the past,

My history is far from gone, it stretches wide and vast.
```

**What am I?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> Mead

"My source is borne upon the wing of valkyries of gold,

They work their magic summer long then winter through the cold,"

> Bees make honey

"Once the black and golds are done I'm plucked with careful hand,"

> Honey collected by beekeepers

"And left to swim among the shrooms until it's time to stand,

And in that time my power grows as was the hand's intent,"

> The honey is left to ferment into mead

"Til even mighty fall like fools when my power is spent,"

> Mead gets people drunk

"Though fewer know me by the days, some think I'm in the past,

My history is far from gone, it stretches wide and vast."

> Mead was more popular historically than in the modern age

Comment: You've pretty much got it with your third spoiler.  Want to adjust the answer and I'll mark correct and add a full explanation?

Comment: Sure! Gimme a sec

Comment: That's pretty spot on actually.  No need for a full explanation from me.  +1

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly certain this is about:

> Beer

Once the black and golds are done I'm plucked with careful hand

> refers to barley and rye

And in that time my power grows as was the hand's intent

> refers to fermentation

Til even mighty fall like fools when my power is spent

> is pretty obvious at this point

and might I add, Nice Riddle!

Comment: It's not beer!  Can't stand the stuff to be honest.  Good explanations though they are, you haven't solved the full puzzle.  (also, thanks!)

Comment: Ahhh, then whiskey? It must be some sort of alcohol. I don't drink so I am not familiar with the different types, but I will keep looking.

Comment: It's not whiskey either.  Not a fan of it at all.  :/

Comment: Try and work out the rest of the lines.  The black and golds have nothing to do with 'barley and rye'.  +1 anyway though

Answer (score 1):

Bit out on a limb, but:

> Motorcycle

because:

My source is borne upon the wing of valkyries of gold,

> http://powersports.honda.com/2015/gold-wing-valkyrie.aspx

They work their magic summer long then winter through the cold,

> TT races (http://www.iomtt.com/), Ice Speedway

Once the black and golds are done I'm plucked with careful hand,

> choose your own colors

And left to swim among the shrooms until it's time to stand,

> motorcycles sound like *shroom* while moving

And in that time my power grows as was the hand's intent,

> throttle is controlled by hand

Til even mighty fall like fools when my power is spent,

> no fuel left?

Though fewer know me by the days, some think I'm in the past,

> classic bikes

My history is far from gone, it stretches wide and vast.

> harley davidson

Comment: Nope.  I like those too though.